# ADF input form issue when navigating away

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a form that I'm using to enter data.
I'm calling the Create action using an invoke action on refresh set on ifNeeded.

The problem I have is that when I try to navigate away with empty fields the form validation stops me from doing so. 
I know the Create action shouldn't be doing this as Oracle changed that to CreateInsert but I think this is because one of the entity object attributes is of type DBSequence and to my knowledge that sets a dummy value of -1 until the db trigger changes it.

What can I do to enable the user to leave the page empty and navigate away?

Comment: Thanks to User404, I solved it by setting immediate to true on the navigation item that the user clicks on should they want to navigate away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set immediate to true.
More info about this attribute: http://adfpractice-fedor.blogspot.be/2012/02/understanding-immediate-attribute.html

Comment: That did it. Thanks! I set it on my navigation item